# Using $push operator for update MongoDB document

Tags: c++, arrays, mongodb, push

I have MongoDB document with structure like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56ebce0d1e3c51fe6a5053f3"),
"timestamp" : 1458294285,
"values" : [ 
    {
        "offset" : 132,
        "packets" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "type1",
                "data" : "some_data1"
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "type2",
                "data" : "some_data2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I use it for storage time series data.
I want to create the query which insert a **packet** in **packets** array.
I use MongoDB c++ legacy driver 1.1.0.
When I will execute twice code below with equal timestamp and offset:

```
mongo::BSONObj query = BSON("timestamp" << timestamp);
mongo::BSONObj mainObj = 
BSON ("$push" << BSON("values" << BSON("offset" << timestampOffset <<
                                       "packets" << BSON_ARRAY(obj))));
connection.update(collectionName, query, mainObj, true);
```

I have result like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56f90c1a3b20b7c1f61dccf7"),
    "timestamp" : 1459080000,
    "values" : [ 
        {
            "offset" : 68457,
            "packets" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : "type1",
                    "data" : "some_data1"
                }
                ]
        }, 
        {
            "offset" : 68457,
            "packets" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : "type2",
                    "data" : "some_data2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Can somebody help me create right query for insert data into the document with specific structure?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot first create a BSON_ARRAY containing all of the `packets` information for a particular `offset`? That will definitely be the most efficient.

Comment: I used the approach like you describe before. I created the big document which contains **packets** for 2 minutes. But I have many chances to lose information because of specificity of application lifetime. Then I decided to store information with bigger frequency, but with previous logic: 1 document for packets for 2 minutes.

Comment: I see. Well, then, I think you can only do this: find the document,  check if its `values` array contains an object with the same `offset` as the datapoint you are adding; if yes, grab the `packets` array, add your new datapoint to the array, and then create the update `offset` object containing the new `values` array; if no, just create a new object containing your datapoint. Basically, I believe you have to deconstruct and then build it back up. I have not found any other way to do it thus far. :/ @Shaikhutdinov

Comment: (The `$` array positional operator might be helpful: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/, depending on what you need/want to do.)

Comment: I can't provide you with actual codes since I am not accessible to be a machine right now. All the best!

Comment: I think easier and better to form objects with **offset** and **packets** in memory and flush it by a timer. Thank you for advice!

Comment: That was actually sort of what I meant, :/ (I say sort of because it really sounds exactly like what I meant to say, but you don't seem to think so, haha!)